# How to get all the users in xmpp / ejabber using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmpp, jabber, ejabberd

I know how get users from console but i do not know how to write its Ruby code so I can get all the users in my website.

Get all registered users:

```
sudo ejabberdctl registered_users domain_name
```

Get all online users:

```
sudo ejabberdctl connected_users
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ODBC database as back-end, you could try getting the number of registered users directly from counting the lines in the users table. I guess it's not really possible to access/query mnesia from Ruby.

Comment: No i am not using ODBC database.